# Regarding the Laplace transform of a random variable (Basic Query)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, laplace-transform

We know that the Laplace transform of a random variable is actually the Laplace transform of the probability density function of that random variable. Therefore my question is as follows. If we have a random variable $X$ then is it right to write the Laplace transform of $max(X,t)$ (here $t$ is a constant) as follows $$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx}f_X(x)dX$$ or will it be different? Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: (assuming $X$ is nonnegative random variable), it'll be different, because the pdf of $X$ and $\max\{X,t\}$ are different, do you know how to find the pdf of $\max\{X,t\}$?

Comment: @RizkyRezaFujisaki I think I know how to find the CDF of $Y=max(X,t)$ (which is $\text{probability that Y is less than equal to c is}=1+\int_t^cf_X(x)dx$). And then differentiate this expression with respect to $c$ will give the pdf of $Y$ I think so. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: A bit wrong, sorry, you have to divide into 3 cases, when $c<t$, $c=t$, and $c>t$, for first case, the cdf is $0$, for $c=t$, it would be equal to $\int_0^t f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x$, and for the last one, it is $\int_0^c f_X(x)\mathrm{d}x$, to find the pdf, you just can take the derivative of the cdf for case $c>t$, but for case $c=t$, you dont have to do anything, just let it be, because $\max\{X,t\}$ is mixed discrete and continous RV now

Comment: @RizkyRezaFujisaki thanks alot for correcting me and telling me the right way. I think, the method provided below by Liron will result in same answer for Laplace transform as obtained from your procedure. However, the method provided below is easier (e.g. if we have to find the Laplace transform of some function of $max(X,t)$ then the method provided below is simple. Just put $e^{-s\times g(t)}F(t)+\int_t^{\infty}e^{-s\times g(x)}f(x)dx$ here I am assuming $g(X)$ to be the function of random variable. Now we can see that we have not found the pdf of $g(X)$ yet we have Laplace transform.)

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a non-negative continuous random variable with density $f$ and $t>0$ is a constant then the Laplace Transform of $Y=\max\{X,t\}$ is:
$$
\mathbb{E}[e^{-sY}]=\int_0^t e^{-st}f(x) dx+\int_t^\infty e^{-sx}f(x) dx=F(t)e^{-st}+\int_t^\infty e^{-sx}f(x) dx.
$$